# Exception when parsing a message

Tags: messagebroker

I am using a message set to parse a file and I am getting the following exception.I am not able to understand what it actually means.Please help me understand and resolve the problem.

```
<ParserException>
        <File>/build/S000_P/src/MTI/MTIforBroker/MtiImbParser2/MtiImbFIHandler.cpp</File>
        <Line>1017</Line>
        <Function>MtiImbFIHandler::endMessageContent</Function>
        <Type></Type>
        <Name></Name>
        <Label></Label>
        <Catalog>BIPmsgs</Catalog>
        <Severity>3</Severity>
        <Number>5288</Number>
        <Text>MTI. Not all the buffer was used when reading message</Text>
        <Insert>
         <Type>2</Type>
         <Text>0</Text>
        </Insert>
        <Insert>
         <Type>2</Type>
         <Text>1659</Text>
        </Insert>
       </ParserException>
```

Comment: See this link: http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=11050

Answer (score 0):

This kind of error happens when the message set "ends" before the data.
For example:
we have got a msg set like this:
NAME - 5 CHAR
SURNAME - 5 CHAR

Data is:
MARIOROSSIAAAAA

Parsed will raise that kind of exception because the msg set don't expect the string "AAAAA" but only:
NAME    = "MARIO"
SURNAME = "ROSSI"

Without the precise example is not possibile go any further.